# socket.io getting all rooms when using a node.js cluster

Tags: node.js, socket.io

So I have the following code which works great but only when I run node.js as a single thread  (non cluster env)

```
function getActiveRooms(io) {
        // Convert map into 2D list:
        // ==> [['4ziBKG9XFS06NdtH', Set(1)], ['room1', Set(2)], ...]
        const arr = Array.from(io.sockets.adapter.rooms);
        console.log('total rooms ' + arr.length)
        // Filter rooms whose name exist in set:
        // ==> [['room1', Set(2)], ['room2', Set(2)]]
        const filtered = arr.filter(room => !room[1].has(room[0]))
        // Return only the room name:
        // ==> ['room1', 'room2']
        const actives = filtered.map(i => i[0]);
        console.log('active rooms ' + actives)
        return actives;
    }
```

but, when I run it in a 32 cluster node (32 CPU / cores PC) I will only get a single room per cluster per the 32 new rooms, and when I join with the 33rd room, it will add it round robin to the 1st node instance will now return 2 rooms.

so the question is, how do I go about getting all rooms from ALL 32 node.js socket.io running clusters?

I am using the latest `"@socket.io/cluster-adapter": "^0.2.0",` but the question still remains, how do I get a list of all rooms across clusters? thank you!

thanks

Sean

Comment: https://socket.io/docs/v4/redis-adapter/

Comment: Actually there's a [cluster adapter](https://socket.io/docs/v4/cluster-adapter/) now too, I didn't realise they had added one.

Comment: Reaching into `io.sockets.adapter.rooms` will not work with clustering.  That will only get you data that the local adapter has.  I don't think socket.io directly supports (in documented APIs that are unlikely to change) getting all room names when in a clustered environment.

Comment: hi guys, yes I am using the latest ```"@socket.io/cluster-adapter": "^0.2.0",``` but the question still remains, how do I get a list of all rooms across clusters? thank you!

Comment: Brute force, you could query every single cluster process for which rooms it has and build a union of what everyone reports.  If you're using the redis-based adapter, presumably all the rooms are in redis somewhere and you'd have to find out where and query it from redis directly.

Answer (score 0):

found what I needed:
`await io.fetchSockets();`
will get sockets from all clusters